# Why does Object.defineProperty make a property invisible when logged?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, defineproperty

I'm trying to understand why using `Object.defineProperty` makes a property not visible when the object is logged in the console.

For instance:

```js
let foo = {};

Object.defineProperty(foo, "a", {
  get() { return "a"; }
});

Object.defineProperty(foo, "b", {
  get() { return "b"; },
  enumerable: true
});

console.log( foo ); // returns {}
```

I do understand that `enumerable` will affect the outcome of a `for...in` loop or the `Object.keys()` static method.
But I don't get why `console.log(foo)` returns `{}`, regardless of the use of `enumerable`, and even if I start by declaring foo as `let foo = { a: 'bar' };`

Thanks!

Comment: What console are you looking at? Every engine has its own implementation, every runtime comes with its own gui.

Comment: I *do* see the getters in the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4On21.png

Comment: "*even if I start by declaring `let foo = { a: 'bar' };`*" - the `Object.defineProperty` call *overwrites* the initial data property, the result is indistinguishable from starting with an empty object.

Comment: Is `Object.defineProperty` even relevant? For instance, take a look at `const woo={get a(){return 1}}`. To me this question actually reads: "Why do getters appear differently to fields in the console?"